# Algebra of Endomorphisms of a functor $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

Recently, I was reading a paper and stumbled upon something for which I don't find the formal definition unfortunately in any textbook that have in my hands. It's the notion of the endomorphism algebra of a functor $\mathcal{F}$, of course I can imagine that there are some restrictions for that functor but I am completely unaware! Can you help me?

So can you give me the formal definition of the algebra $End({\mathcal{F}})$?

Comment: I am not sure, but isn't this just the set of natural transformations from the functor to itself with composition as operation? Note that the term 'algebra' is sometimes used as another word for 'monoid'.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch thank you for your response, I do know that and indeed that's exactly the set of natural transformations, though I am looking for a formal definition somewhere! Do you know any kind of reference that comprises the above?

Comment: What exactly isn't formal in the definition you know? Or is it just that you want a reference for this notion? This might be difficult because since we can consider functors as the objects of a category with natural transformations between them as morphisms, there is no need for the explicit definition of the endomorphism algebra of a functor as it is included in the definition of endomorphism algebra of the object of a category. But then again, I do not really know the literature that well.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endomorphism+ring

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch thank you both! You helped me a lot, I didn't know that there exists the notion of an endomorphism algebra for a given object in an arbitrary cateogry,